# Working with array of structures in C using pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to learn better how pointer work in C and pointer to pointer to structure things broke my mind. Here I have 3 questions:

1. If I have a structure and a pointer to pointer **tests to this structure (so this is something like an array) how can I use p to access to array members (the best way)? tests[i]->id fails (example of source is below)
2. Having that monstrous line with pointers below is something bad to have in the code but I would like to do work with it as well. I think I've mistaken with its template, the output for every next structure's address looks like jumps 32 bytes ahead, while size of structure is only 4 bytes. So in the line I want to (1) take the initial address of the tests top pointer, (2) add to it size of the structure TestCase multiplied by `i` so it points to correct array element and (3) add offset of the id field of the structure. And after that I will get address where I can write the `id` value in memory, right? Am I doing this correct?
3. Why *tests value was changed? Buffer overflow?

   ```
   struct TestCase{
       int id;
   };
   int main()
   {
       TestCase ** tests;
       cout << "Size of TestCase: " << sizeof(TestCase) << endl;
       *tests = (TestCase*)malloc(sizeof(TestCase*)*5);
       cout << "*tests = " << *tests << endl;
       for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           //*(int*)(tests+sizeof(TestCase)*i+(int)&(((struct TestCase*)NULL)->id)) = i;

           int addr = tests; // address of structures array in memmory;
           addr += sizeof(TestCase)*i; //address of current structure;
           addr += (int)&(((struct TestCase*)NULL)->id); // Adding id parameter offset in memory to current address
           *(int*)addr = i; // setting id for current structure equal to i
           cout << (int*)(tests+sizeof(TestCase)*i+(int)&(((struct TestCase*)NULL)->id)) << endl;
       }
       cout << "*tests = " << *tests << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   Output is:

   ```
   Size of TestCase: 4
   *tests = 0x600048600
   0x23ab90
   0x23abb0
   0x23abd0
   0x23abf0
   0x23ac10
   *tests = 0x600000000
   ```

P.S.: Updated cycle code from one monstrous line to step by step actions.

Comment: Sorry, I can't read that line of code, thus can't understand what the intent is.  Thus I can't help you figure out a better way of writing it!  Please explain what the *intent* of the code is.

Comment: I asked not about cout, it was used just for debugging, @cacho Or do you think it adds something different to the source logic?

Comment: `*tests = (TestCase*)malloc(sizeof(TestCase*));` Right here you already are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Instead of putting everything on two long lines of code, why not break it into smaller steps, storing the intermediate results.

Comment: @NeilKirk Updated source so it is now step by step cycle;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want `tests` to be an `array-of-pointers-to-struct-TestCase` with 5 pointers to 5 structs, then you need to

- allocate an array of 5 pointers, and
- initialize each pointer by allocating memory for the struct

Like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TestCase
{
    int id;
};

int main( void )
{
    int i;
    struct TestCase **tests;

    // allocate memory for an array of 5 pointers
    tests = malloc( 5 * sizeof(struct TestCase *) );
    if ( tests == NULL )
        exit( 1 );

    // allocate memory for 5 structures (and save each pointer in the array)
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        tests[i] = malloc( sizeof(struct TestCase) );
        if ( tests[i] == NULL )
            exit( 1 );
    }

    // initialize the id in each struct
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        tests[i]->id = i;

    // print the id in each struct
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        printf( "%d\n", tests[i]->id );

    // free memory
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        free( tests[i] );
    free( tests );

    return 0;
}
```

---

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem described in point 2.  Here's the code I tried (which I placed ahead of the code that frees memory)

```
printf( "%p\n", tests );
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    intptr_t addr = (intptr_t)tests;
    addr += sizeof(struct TestCase)*i;
    addr += (int)&(((struct TestCase*)NULL)->id);

    printf( "%p\n", (void *)addr );
}
```

The output from the code is

```
0xc03950
0xc03950
0xc03954
0xc03958
0xc0395c
0xc03960
```

The address advances by 4 bytes as expected.  Note that I changed the type of `addr` to `intptr_t` to guarantee that the pointer can be cast properly, but that doesn't effect the math in the subsequent two lines.

Comment: Thanks for solution with tests[i]->id. Now I see my problem. Points 1 and 3 are answered by this, but still I want to do something with 2. This line looks so awesome to me, that it looks like code obfuscation by itself ) Updated that line to 3 lines in step by step instructions as people asked in comments.

Comment: @ArturKorobeynyk I wasn't able to duplicate the problem where the address jumps by 32 bytes. I've updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Well, does not matter already. Thanks dude! Thanks to your explanation I was able to deal with point 2. I posted the solution below. You saved my day )

Answer (score 1):

1. In your code tests is triple *, remove the additional * from the malloc line and test[0]->id assignments will work.
2. If you need a high level access to an offset, assign values as you initially wanted to in question 1. IE - tests[0]->id = 0x3834 , or memcpy for dynamic assignments. There´s no need for all those references and casts.
3. Because tests was reassinged in the first line of your iterator.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but as for 2. that was the point, to make that line work ) Just for fun

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user3386109 I was able finally to do everything I wanted. Well, instead of writing to address using creepy formula I am now reading from address using the same creepy formula:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    struct TestCase{
        int ida;
        int idb;
    };

    int main()
    {
        TestCase ** tests; //create pointer to pointer
        cout << "Size of TestCase: " << sizeof(TestCase) << endl;
        tests = malloc(sizeof(TestCase*)*5);
        if(tests == NULL)
            exit(1);
        for(int i=0; i< 5; i++)
        {
            tests[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct TestCase));
            if(tests[i] == NULL)
                exit(1);
        }
        cout << "*tests = " << *tests << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tests[i]->ida = i;
            tests[i]->idb = i+6;
            cout << std::hex << &(tests[i]->idb) << ": " << *(long*)((long)(long*)(tests[i])+(long)&(((TestCase *)NULL)->idb)) << endl;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            free(tests[i]);
        }
        cout << "*tests = " << *tests << endl;
        free(tests);
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
    $ ./a.exe
    Size of TestCase: 8
    *tests = 0x600048630
    0x600048634: 6
    0x600048654: 7
    0x600048674: 8
    0x600048694: 9
    0x6000486b4: a
    *tests = 0x600048630
```